# Как сделать GET запрос с параметрами?

Tags: json, ios, swift, swift4

Всем здравствуйте, нигде не могу найти информации как сделать GET запрос с вложенными в него параметрами?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: а дописать к адресу `http://examle.com/api?param1=foo&param2=bar` пробовали?

Comment: Нет, а зачем это?

Comment: Это же не поможет

Comment: Метод GET удобен тем, что прост в эксплуатации. Но у него есть недостатки. Во-первых, методом GET нельзя передавать большие объемы информации, потому что данные, передаваемые этим методом входят в соств URL, длина которого ограничена.

Пример: ссылка http://dayte2.com/?u=shaman&act=state&num=9 содержит данные, передаваемые методом GET. Эти данные идут после знака вопроса.

Comment: https://dayte2.com/get-post-methods

Comment: Это я понимаю, но видите ли у меня это все находится в заголовках http.  И то что я вставлю в url не прокатит

Comment: я конечно не swift программист но RESTful знаю, если у вас в теле запроса передаются данные то это POST, если в строке это GET

Comment: Пойдемте в чат?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87318/discussion-between-marshall-and-arendach).

Comment: У GET запроса ограничение в 2048 символов. То что вы хотите передать нужно передавать POST запросом иначе никак.